# Como generar reporte en Jasper si no se cumple la condicion del WHERE

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports

Hola comunidad les comento el problema que tengo, estoy generando un reporte de deudas de clientes con la siguiente query:

```
SELECT
     COALESCE(sum(F.total),0) AS Compra,
    CC.saldo - sum(F.total) AS deuda,
     C."razon_social" AS cliente,
     CC."saldo" AS saldo
FROM
     "public"."factura" F INNER JOIN "public"."cliente" C ON F."uncliente_id_cliente" = C."id_cliente"
     INNER JOIN "public"."ctacte" CC ON C."razon_social" = CC."razonsocial"
WHERE
     F.fecha >= $P{fechaInicial} AND F.fecha <= $P{fechaFinal}
GROUP BY
     razon_social,
     saldo
```

El problema es que, como veran en la condicion se solicita una fecha inicial y final, es decir un rango, mi problema es que si no hay ninguna factura emitida en ese rango el jasper me devuelve DOCUMENT HAS NOT PAGES, pero yo necesito que me lo genere igual! Alguno tiene idea de como hacerlo? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una consulta con un count, si trae registros generas el reporte, sino presentas un mensaje "No hay registros disponibles"

---

Por otro lado si lo que quieres es generar el reporte sin el detalle

Puedes cambiar la propiedad **When No Data** en el XML es `whenNoDataType`, puede intentar usar el valor **All Sections, No Detail**

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta jasilva, lo que sucede es que quiero que se genere siempre el reporte, la condicion de fecha me determina el campo "compra", simplemente quiero que si no hubo ninguna factura emitida el campo compra aparezca en 0 y el resto de los campos normalmente, de momento me dice que no hay paginas, pero tampoco quiero generar el reporte vacio, sino que si se vean los detalles

Comment: Te recomiendo que subas tu archivo jrxml para ver que tienes en este momento

Comment: pude solucionarlo quitando el where y colocando un CASE en el sum :)